# find_all in beautiful soup does not show all the data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the reading time from this [website](https://proshore.eu/resources/) using its class in beautiful soup. But I am only getting six results but there are more than that.

```
    web = requests.get("https://proshore.eu/resources/").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web,'xlml')
    
    reading_time = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "playground-read-time"})
```

Comment: Content is loaded dynamically while scrolling - Watch out for post request in your dev tools xhr section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That content is being loaded dynamically, via ajax post calls (like I see HedgeHog confirmed). On top of this, website has some sort of protections, and will block you 'for malicious activities' if you don't give it some time to breathe between requests. The following code should return some meaningful response:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time as t

s = requests.Session()

url = 'https://proshore.eu/resources/'

s.get(url)
t.sleep(2)
counter = 0
df_list = []
while True:
    try:
        payload = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'page': f'{counter}'
        }
        r = s.post('https://proshore.eu/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data=payload)
        if len(r.text) < 10:
            print('all done')
            break
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.select('div.playground-item')
        for x in items:
            try:
                title = x.select_one('h4.playground-title').get_text(strip=True)
            except Exception as e:
                title = 'title not specified'
            try:
                author = x.select_one('div.playground-author-name').get_text(strip=True)
            except Exception as e:
                author = 'author not specified'
            try:
                read_time = x.select_one('span.playground-read-time-text').get_text(strip=True)
            except Exception as e:
                read_time = 'read_time not specified'
            df_list.append((title, author, read_time))
        counter = counter + 1
        t.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['Title', 'Author', 'Reading time'])
print(df)
```

The result:

|  | Title | Author | Reading time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 steps for delivering exceptional User Onboarding in SaaS | Sumit Shrestha | 8 minutes |
| 1 | KSS: Migrating from manual to automated QA testing | Sumit Shrestha | 4 minutes |
| 2 | Micro-SaaS: what it is and why it matters | Roshan Bhattarai | 6 minutes |
| 3 | How to scale microservices without using Kubernetes | Babish Shrestha | 6 minutes |
| 4 | Driving eCommerce excellence through innovative software development | Bipin Manandhar | 3 minutes |
| 5 | Tackling turnaround: how to handle changes during software development | Milan Khanal | 7 minutes |
| 6 | KSS: Level up your website with Hotjar | Sumit Shrestha | 4 minutes |
| 7 | Getting Rid of Rolling Deadlines | Samir Maharjan | 6 minutes |
| 8 | The challenges and solutions of scaling software development for startups | Jeroen van der Horst | 5 minutes |
| 9 | How It Works: Teams As A Service | Haico Duisters | 6 minutes |
| 10 | Nepal: A serious contender in software development outsourcing | Jeroen van der Horst | 6 minutes |
| 11 | KSS: How to use Blackfire to monitor the performance of PHP application | Sumit Shrestha | 4 minutes |
| 12 | 7 common mistakes in IT outsourcing – and tips to avoid making them | Jeroen van der Horst | 6 minutes |
| 13 | EU-Startups Summit | author not specified | read_time not specified |
| 14 | Scaling Startups In The Cloud: Ways To Make That Journey | Haico Duisters | 7 minutes |
| 15 | SaaStr Europa | author not specified | read_time not specified |
| 16 | All Onboard: Overcoming the challenges of project ownership with managed teams | Sumit Shrestha | 5 minutes |
| 17 | Proshore Bootcamp: A free program for early-stage IT professionals in Nepal | Roshan Bhattarai | read_time not specified |
| 18 | From micromanaging to self-managing remote software development | Sumit Shrestha | 3 minutes |
| 19 | Digital Product Labs: How Proshore helped sync listings & orders across Etsy & Shopify | Sumit Shrestha | 3 minutes |
| 20 | Our Culture Club: Bridging The Gaps | Sumit Shrestha | 3 minutes |
| 21 | The Netherlands + Nepal = Proshore | Sumit Shrestha | 4 minutes |
| 22 | Automation For Your Business: The Value Of Successful Implementation | Babish Shrestha | read_time not specified |
| 23 | From Monolith To Microservices: What We’ve Learned From Helping Clients Make That Journey | Babish Shrestha | read_time not specified |
| 24 | Gain an online edge with synergy in your development team | Jeroen van der Horst | read_time not specified |
| 25 | Remote development teams: three commonly heard challenges (and how to tackle them!) | Jeroen van der Horst | read_time not specified |
| 26 | Doing business in Nepal | Jeroen van der Horst | read_time not specified |
| 27 | Remote team: how to increase the quality of their output | Steven van Kempen | read_time not specified |
| 28 | Why Nepal? | Jeroen van der Horst | read_time not specified |
| 29 | Nepalese IT students can really build the country | Roshan Bhattarai | read_time not specified |
| 30 | Hiring a single developer while reaping the rewards of an entire team | Jeroen van der Horst | read_time not specified |
| 31 | Sheetal Shrestha: From Intern Quality Analyst to Project Lead | Prakash Bhusal | read_time not specified |
| 32 | Karan Shakya: On starting a career as a UI/UX designer | Prakash Bhusal | read_time not specified |
| 33 | IT developer in practice: “Proshore is a well managed IT company” | Prakash Bhusal | read_time not specified |
| 34 | Proshore’s 10th anniversary- Walking together with technology | Roshan Bhattarai | read_time not specified |
| 35 | IT job in Nepal: “We want team members to look forward to Mondays” | Prakash Bhusal | read_time not specified |
| 36 | A remote development team: what are the pros and cons? | Jeroen van der Horst | read_time not specified |